# is it possible to record mp3 in iphone sdk?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, mp3

I know we can record audio and save in document Directory as caf file.is it possible to save it as MP3 file..can I give file extension as mp3 while saving?bcos I have to send it to server?is it possible without using 3rd party libs like LAME?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052092/iphone-avaudiorecorder-how-can-i-record-to-an-mp3) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871940/how-to-record-an-audio-file-in-mp3-format)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005598/looking-for-a-way-to-encode-mp3-on-iphone). As far as I know there is no straightforward way to record as mp3 in iphone. But these links talks about workarounds. I havent tried any of them, so I can't help there...Hope it leads you to good...:)

And see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676750/how-to-record-something-other-than-linear-pcm-on-iphone) too..